# Which books to choose for optimization?

Tags: optimization

I'm considering to choose between "Convex Optimization" by Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe, and Yurii Nesterov's "Lectures on Convex Optimization" to supplement for my university course. I have had Calculus and Linear Algebra, my course covers constrained and unconstrained convex optimization, linear programming and constrain programming so i want to know which one of these two books will be good for me. The lecture i'm having mostly just focus on the implementation of the method but not the mathematical proof behind it so i want to learn more about the math behind optimization algorithms. I've read a few section from each book and personally i think Yurii Nesterov's book is more rigorous and easy to understand, but i still want to ask because i don't have enough time to study both and i want a strong foundation on this subject for my AI major.

P/S: I'm also really enjoy rigorous books like Apostol's Calculus I,II so i want to know which of the two books above have similar style.